# Trouble in understanding a proof in sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Theorem** $:$

> Prove that, the range set of the sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ is finite if for two fixed natural numbers $m_{0} , n_{0}$
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{r + n_{0}} x_{i} \leq n_{0}.$$ and
>
> $$\sum_{i=1}^{r + m_{0}} \frac {1} {x_{i}} \leq m_{0}.$$ $,$ where $r$ is any non-negative integer.

**Proof** $:$

$(x_{1} + x_{2} + ... + x_{n_{0}}) + (x_{n_{0} + 1} + x_{n_{0} + 2} + ...  + x_{2n_{0}}) + ... +  (x_{(m_{0} -1) n_{0} + 1} + x_{(m_{0} - 1) n_{0} + 2} + ... + x_{m_{0} n_{0}}) \leq n_{0} + n_{0} + ... + n_{0}$ ($m_{0}$-times) $ \leq m_{0} n_{0} .$

$\implies$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} x_{i} \leq N$$ $,$ where $N = m_{0}n_{0}$.

Similarly it can be proved that $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac {1} {x_{i}} \leq N.$$

Now by Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we have

$$[\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\sqrt {x_{i}})^{2}].[\sum_{i=1}^{N} (\sqrt {\frac {1} {x_{i}}})^{2}] > [\sum_{i=1}^{N} ({\sqrt {x_{i}}}.{\frac {1} {\sqrt {x_{i}}}})^{2}].$$ [Equality does not occur].

$\implies N.N > N^{2}$ i.e. $N^{2} > N^{2}$, a contradiction.

This proves our claim.

I don't understand why contradiction arises and why equality does not hold in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.If $x_{i} = k$ $,$ for some $k \in \mathbb R$ for $i = 1 , 2 , ... , N$ then what will happen?Please someone make it clear to me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post a specific question?

Comment: @OnceUponACrinoid look my latest edit.